# D3.js - Problem in filling colors in piechart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am not able to fill the colours in pie chart designed using D3.js

```
   var chartData =[];
   // var rcolor = d3.scale.ordinal(d3.schemeDark2);
    color = d3.scale.category20c();
    function plot(data) {
        chartData = data;
        console.log("piechart.js executing");
        TransformChartData(chartData, chartOptions);
        BuildPie("chart", chartData, chartOptions);
    }

    function BuildPie(id, chartData, options) {

        var divisionRatio = 2.5;
        var legendoffset = 0;

        chart = d3.select("#" + id + " .innerCont");
        var xVarName = options[0].xaxis;
        var yVarName = options[0].yaxis;
        width = $(chart[0]).outerWidth(),
        height = $(chart[0]).outerHeight(),
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / divisionRatio;    

        arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .outerRadius(radius)
                .innerRadius(radius - 200);

        chart = chart
                .append("svg")  //append svg element inside #chart
                .attr("width", width)    //set width
                .attr("height", height)  //set height
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / divisionRatio) + "," + ((height / divisionRatio) + 30) + ")");

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                    .sort(null)
                    .value(function (d) {
                        return d.data;
                    });

        var g = chart.selectAll(".arc")
                    .data(pie(runningData))
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "arc");

        var count = 0;
        var path = g.append("path")
                    .attr("d", arc)
                    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {return color(i)});

        g.append("text")
         .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
         .attr("dy", ".35em")
         .style("text-anchor", "middle")
         .style("opacity", 1)
         .text(function (d) {
             return d.data.bankName + " (" + d.data.data + ")";
         });
    }

    function TransformChartData(chartData, opts) {
        var result = [];
        var yVarName = opts[0].yaxis;
        var xVarName = opts[0].xaxis;

        for (var i in chartData) {
                ditem = {};
                ditem[xVarName] = chartData[i][xVarName];
                ditem[yVarName] = chartData[i][yVarName];
                result.push(ditem);
        }
        runningData = result;
        return;
    }

    var chartOptions = [{
        "xaxis": "bankName",
        "yaxis": "data"
    }]
```

Chart is getting generated using chartData, but the color is not getting filled inside piechart. Any way to fill the colours in piechart randomly ? Can someone help in idenfying the problem and way to work with this.Thanks in advance :)